# sed via stdin not working as expected

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a line, which I have grepped from a file, that I am attempting to extract only the value within quotes.

```
$db_name                = "blah";
```

I'm using this pipe to parse it out:

```
| awk '{print $NF}' | tr -d \'\" | sed  -r 's/.$//'
```

However, this appears to result in this:

```
blah;
```

Whereas, I would expect the `sed` incantation to remove the last character. I've also tried with `sed -r` and `sed -e`, which don't seem to have any effect.

As I will only need to remove the `;` in each case for this, I tried `sed 's/;//'`, which worked, but I'd still like to know why the regex didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is probably an invisible character following the `;` like a whitespace or a carriage return (from a DOS CRLF newline). Anyhow, your commands are clumsy and can easily break. A simple `sed 's/[^ "]*"//;s/".*//'` (remove everything upto the first `"` and everything starting from the second `"`) replaces the whole thing and is more rubust.

Comment: `awk  -F'"' '{ print $(NF - 1) }'` would also also work. Not sure why the `tr` deletes both single and double quotes -- can the input value be quoted either way ?

Comment: See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) - different symptoms, same problem (probably).

Comment: You don't need grep, tr, and/or sed when using awk. If you show us whatever grep command you're using we can show you a single awk command to do everything you're currently doing with multiple commands and pipelines.

Comment: and similarly, since you use `tr` to remove the quotes, you could also have it remove the semicolon

Comment: anyway, pipe the output before the sed to `od -c` to see what it actually contains

Comment: Which `sed` do you use? With GNU sed, `printf "blah;" | sed 's/.$//'` I get `blah`

Answer (score 1):

**Perl:**

```
| awk '{print $NF}' | tr -d \'\" | perl -lpe 'chop'
```

**Raku:**

```
| awk '{print $NF}' | tr -d \'\" | raku -pe '.=chop'
```

Sample Input:

```
echo '$db_name                = "blah";'
```

Sample Output (both code examples):

```
blah
```

https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop
https://docs.raku.org/routine/chop

Answer (score 1):

If you use `awk ... | grep ... | sed ...` (or any other combination thereof) you are doing something seriously wrong.

If you use awk, then do all in awk and if you use sed then do all in sed. And both of them can do what grep does.

Having said this: sed is retaining the last character, because you haven't told it to remove it. Do it the following way (notice that here we are only cutting out the *last* quoted string. If there are several like `foo "bar1" bar "bar2"` only "bar2" would be printed):

```
your_input | sed 's/.*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

or

```
sed 's/.*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' /path/to/inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW,

1. if you are using `bash`, and
2. the only quotes are those around the last word, then

you could capture each line of `grep` output and use the shell's text manipulation functions, e.g.,

```
# take advantage of the default behaviour of read
while read; do
    # remove everything upto and including the first "
    lastPart=${REPLY#*\"}
    # remove the second " and everything after it
    wantedPart=${lastPart%\"*}
    echo $wantedPart
done <<<$(grep somePattern someFile)
```

This is more of a fun exercise than anything else, it won't necessarily be robust, and your data has to be reliably regular for this to work. I totally understand the use of awk to get started....